# Custom backend authenticate success without returning User object

Tags: django, authentication

I'm writing a backend to validate users based on tokens from AWS Cognito. Is it possible to write an authenticate() method for a backend that "succeeds" without returning a Django User object?

For example:

```
class CustomBackend(BaseBackend):
     def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
          if token_is_valid(request.COOKIES["auth_jwt"]):
              # Success, let the user through
          else:
              # Failure, redirect to login page to get token from Cognito
```

My understanding of "authenticate()" is that "success" is denoted by returning a User object, and failure by returning None. Can this work or do we need to make User objects based on the tokens so we have a User to return?

Edit: Found something called RemoteUserBackend, which sounds like it might be what I want, but I think has the same issue. Will leave link here in case it is relevant: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend

Comment: how you are expecting to use login afterwards if you don't have user

Comment: I think that is the crux of the question. Is it possible to use something like the LoginRequiredMixin with a backend like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if a "userless backend" is possible, but I solved the problem with middleware, which seems more appropriate.

```
class ValidateTokenMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        token = request.COOKIES.get("auth_jwt", None)
        
        # Here you can validate your token, redirect, set new access token, etc.
```